# Pyqt: Widget won't resize inside of graphics scene

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Placing a widget inside of a graphics scene will only allow the graphics scene to extend but not shrink, setting the graphics scene to the size of the itemsBoundingRect() will not work as the rect will return the size of the widget, which will not shrink when inside of a graphics view in this setup. If anybody could elaborate on what is preventing the widget from shrinking I would be thankful. Placing this same widget in a QScrollArea seems to allow it to shrink.

MRE:

```
class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300,300,1000,1000)

        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
app.setStyle('Fusion')
widget = QWidget()
widget.setStyleSheet("background:red")
widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)

vbox = QVBoxLayout()

def add_btn():
    btn = QPushButton("x")
    btn.setFixedHeight(40)
    vbox.addWidget(btn)
    btn.clicked.connect(btn.deleteLater)
    print(gs.itemsBoundingRect())

def remove_btn(obj):
    obj.deleteLater()
    print(gs.itemsBoundingRect())

btn = QPushButton("add")
btn.clicked.connect(add_btn)
vbox.addWidget(btn)


btn = QPushButton("x")
btn.setFixedHeight(40)
vbox.addWidget(btn)
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: remove_btn(btn))



gv = QGraphicsView()
gv.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
gs = QGraphicsScene()
gs.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.blue))


gs.addWidget(widget)
gv.setScene(gs)

widget.setLayout(vbox)
window.setCentralWidget(gv)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This example just prints the item bounding rect, pressing the add button will add buttons expanding the widget, but the widget never shrinks when getting rid of the buttons. Furthermore, the itemboundingrect is printed on every press.

Comment: Why do you want to resize the scene rect? Also, the size policy of a widget only makes sense when it's added to a layout: just like for the scene, the geometry can only automatically increase, if you want it to "shrink" down to the minimum size you should call `adjustSize()`, but that can only happen after the child widget has been successfully removed from the layout (which could require an indefinite amount of event loop cycles).

Comment: in my case I want to shrink it because I am making a scheduler that prints from the graphicsscene and when entries are removed I need the graphics scene to resize. Originally I had the widget in a scrollArea which resized properly but I needed a zoom functionality. I will look into adjustSize()

Comment: @musicamante Calling adjustSize() seems to work with the exception that I have to delay the adjustSize() call with a timer if I call it right when an entry is deleted.

Comment: @musicamante this is causing problems in my actual project because of what you pointed out is there any way to call adjust size on the main thread?

Comment: You could create a function that calls *both* [`QApplication.processEvents()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) *and then* `adjustSize()`, and only start that function with a single shot timer: `QTimer.singleShot(0, someFunction)`. This *could* be enough to allow the layout to properly process its internal sizes and final geometry.

Comment: @musicmante hmm im still getting crashes :/ I want to take the thread approach and wait for the delete to finish completely, but this seems like a difficult issue to tackle with the way the deleteLater() calls are deferred in the thread.

Comment: No, you can't use threads to access widgets, because UI elements are ***not*** thread safe. Just don't do that, don't even try it: even extremely experienced people had tried, with little success and lots of unnecessary headaches. Direct UI access can ***only*** happen in the main thread. Also, be aware that such a "pseudo-procedural" approach, while could work, is generally discouraged, and a more OOP-affine pattern is always preferred (so, subclasses).

Comment: @musicmante Thanks for your help, I'm going to go ahead and mark this as answered as this is turning into a different question.